# Insert Data with uuid id on oracle 11g will not work

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

if I execute an insert statement with an id which starts with 5, the db server will not committing. With an id that starts not with 5 it will be commiting.

sql statement:

```
INSERT INTO D_ROLEGROUP (ID, VERSION, NAME) VALUES ('582595D1DDFF49D09013E5FC57F7AD01', 1, 'role_group_abc');
```

ddl:

```
CREATE TABLE D_ROLEGROUP
(
    ID VARCHAR2(32) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    VERSION NUMBER(38) NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX NAME_UNIQ_1456146427545 ON D_ROLEGROUP (NAME);
```

db version: 
oracle 11g

Comment: Does the DB server say, literally: "I will not commit this!", or do you get an actual error message?

Comment: no error message, the transaction runs and I stopped it

Comment: Do you maybe mean 'submit' or 'execute' rather than 'commit'? Either way please add the actual error you get. Or if you don't get an error, have you tried the same thing in another session, and haven't rolled that back?

Comment: Yes i mean execute. I have restarted the db server and now it works. How could this strange behavior occur?

Comment: If you had uncommitted changes in another session, inserting a row with the same ID or name value. Then this session would block waiting for that to commit or rollback, so it could tell if there was a primary key or unique index violation.